# How to check the matrix is Hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hermitian-matrices

I have the following matrix

$$A = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 2 & 0\cr 1 & 0 & 1\cr}$$

and

$$adj(\bf{A})=\pmatrix{2 & 0 & -2\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr -2 & 0 & 2\cr}$$

MATLAB says the matrix $A$ is Hermitian. However the conjugate transpose is not equal the matrix $A$.
How to check the matrix is Hermitian ?

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your posts. [Here is a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean $$A = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 2 & 0\cr 1 & 0 & 1\cr}$$
that is Hermitian: its conjugate transpose (which in this case is the transpose, because the matrix is real) is itself.
As for $\pmatrix{2 & 0 & -2\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr -2 & 0 & 2\cr}$, that is the "classical adjoint" or [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix).  It has nothing to do with the Hermitian adjoint or conjugate transpose.  The terminology is unfortunately confusing.

The Matlab command

```
adjoint(A)
```

gives you the classical adjoint of $A$, while

```
A'
```

gives you the Hermitian adjoint.

Comment: You mean that Classical Adjoint is different from Hermitian Adjoint ??  :O   I did not know that.